# Select2 apply bootstrap input-lg

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2-3

How can I implement input-lg class in a select2 dropdown? I wan't my dropdown to have the same size as an input element having a class of input-lg here's what I have so far

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <label for="mobile" class="control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span> Nationality</label>
     <input type="text" id="nationality" name="nationality" class="form-control input-lg" />
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 padding-minimum">
     <label for="mobile" class="control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span> Gender</label>
     <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control select2-container input-lg step2-select" data-placeholder="Select Gender">
         <option></option>
         <option value="1">Male</option>
         <option value="0">Female</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

And here is my script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').select2();
  });
</script>
```

But It seems that once initialized the dropdown is not the same size as an input field having a class of input-lg eventhough I placed a class of input-lg on my select element. Any idea on how to implement this? I just want the select2 to have the same height as the input field

I'm using select2 version 4.0.0 and the css is version 3.5.2 I think

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o2Lcru85/

Comment: This works great thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this [dedicated CSS](https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.0.html) (select2-bootstrap-theme) to work quite well.

```
bower install select2-bootstrap-theme
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2-bootstrap.css">
```

```js
$( "#dropdown" ).select2({
    theme: "bootstrap"
});
```

`select2.full.js` is [told to be required](https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.0.html#rtl-support-and-control-sizing) to be able to manage the sizes, but I seemed to get it working without the "full" version

Answer (score 6):

To make `select` equal in height of input, make following changes in CSS and remove `input-lg` selector from `<select>` it's unnecessary and no use of it

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('select').select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    height: 46px !important;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.33;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
    top: 85% !important;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    line-height: 26px !important;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    border: 1px solid #CCC !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" />
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="mobile" class="control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span> Nationality</label>
    <input type="text" id="nationality" name="nationality" class="form-control input-lg" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 padding-minimum">
    <label for="mobile" class="control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span> Gender</label>
    <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control select2-container step2-select" data-placeholder="Select Gender">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="0">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2Lcru85/)

Comment: This works. But for what it's worth you don't need any of those `!important` declarations. The only thing this is missing is a `width: 100% !important` - the `!important` is needed on that as Select2 calculates the width of the element based on the outer width of its container (thus ignoring padding). The `width` declaration here takes padding into account.

Answer (score 0):

In your css place input-lg+ before you class .select2-container example: `

```
.input-lg+.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    height: 46px !important;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.33;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.input-lg+.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
    top: 85% !important;
}
.input-lg+.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    line-height: 26px !important;
}
.input-lg+.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    border: 1px solid #CCC !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

` 
using @Shehary example

Answer (score 0):

all you need is just set select2 to use bootstrap themes by download select2 add-on CSS

https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme

```
<link href="js/select2-bootstrap-theme/dist/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then on JS part

```
$('.select2').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap"
});
```

(without bootstrap-theme)

[image]

(with bootstrap-theme)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While select2-bootstrap-theme is for Bootstrap v3, You can use this for [Bootstrap v4](https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme).

**Installation**

> $ npm install @ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme

**Usage**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/select2-bootstrap4.css">

$('select').select2({
   theme: 'bootstrap4',
});
```

And here is its [Demo](https://ttskch.github.io/select2-bootstrap4-theme/)